# Raspberry leaves turning red and yellow, help?

Tags: identification, diagnosis, leaves, raspberries

does anyone know why my raspberry leaves are turning red and yellow? It looks like they start turning red first, then eventually they end up yellow with hints of red. 
[image]

[image]

[image][image]

Comment: What part of the world are you in, how long have you had the raspberry plant and is it in a pot or in the ground?

Comment: In the UK. It's in a large container, probably about 80 litre container. This is it's second year, so first time fruiting.

Comment: 80 litres? That's medium dustbin sized, is it really that large? Might be easier to add a photo showing the pot as well, but does the container have drainage holes?

Comment: Yeah, it's definitely about 80 litres, it's one of the big fabric bag pots so the material is fully permeable drainage is good. I'll add a photo to the main post